# simplify degree 2 polynomials over $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I am currently attending a class on scheme theory and we were given the following problem:

Let $f(x,y)=a_1x^2+a_2xy+a_3y^2+a_4x+a_5y+a_6\in\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ be a non-zero polynomial of degree 2. Show that the vanishing locus of $f$ is isomorphic to one of the followig:

1. $V(x^2+y^2-1)$
2. $V(y-x^2)$
3. $V(yx-1)$
4. $V(x^2)$
5. $V(x(x-1))$
6. $V(xy)$
7. $V(x^2+y^2+1)$

We were given the hint that wlog $a_1x^2+a_2xy+a_3y^2\in \{x^2,xy,x^2+y^2\}$ after suitable linear trasnformations. Now for my question:

I understand how you can proof the exercise from the hint (essentially huge case distinction and work everything out by hand if there is a more elegant way please give me a hint). However I am unsure how I can obtain the hint. I know how to change variables to elimante, say $y^2$ but I don't understand how I can then kill $xy$ without creating new potential $y^2$ terms. I feel like there is a trick am missing but I can't seem to make any progress. Any help is appreciated

Comment: The short answer is you can complete the squares and then translate. This kills off the constant terms and the linear terms. This is what the hint is. Then everything you have reduces down to studying the different cases that can occur for different coefficients $a_1,a_2,a_3$ (i.e. when they are zero or nonzero). Try to figure this out and if you cannot, I can write more later.

Comment: Isn't what your saying kind of the opposite of what the hint is saying? I know how to get from the hint to the final statement.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The main issue with what I said is that you need to be careful with say $a=0$ or $a_3=0$ occuring because then there is no square to complete. Outside of that, try completing squares. Rewrite $a_1x^2+a_4x$ as $(x+\frac{a_4}{2a_1})^2-\frac{a_4^2}{4a_1^2}$ if $a_1\neq 0$ and so on. Translate so that only $x^2$ appears.

Comment: @Womm: if you have already killed $y^2$ and have only $ax^2+bxy$ with nonzero $a,b$ as degree 2 terms, change variables $x, y$ to $x'=x, y'=ax+by$ to get only $x'y'$ in degree 2.